# Trying to count words in different lists

Tags: python, for-loop, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying for sentiment analysis to score many comments in a data frame. I have a negative word corpora, and a positive one. I want to add 1 for every positive word, and remove 1 for every negative word in the comment. My code:

```
     text['counts'] = 0
     for i in text.Reviews:
         if i in p:
             text['counts'] += 1
         elif i in n:
             text['counts'] +=-1
```

I want the new column, text.counts to give the comment's score for every comment, but so far I've only managed to get the total count appear on every row (as if my dataframe was one big comment.)

Thank you!

Comment: How about a **dict**, formatted as d = { 'comment_id' : value_of_comment }

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: The same way you implemented your dict with the `counts` key ? But you would have a dict as a value in your current dict. What don't you understand ?

Comment: Well, would I only change the first line of the code, and if not, how do I use the dictionary in the for loop ?

Comment: I will make an answer for you. You will then tell me if it suits you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here, instead of a global count, you have a specific count for each comment. :)
I duplicated the if-statement because I assumed you wouldn't want to check at each iteration, but instead check on something less occurrent, and so, more memory efficient. :d

```
text['commentsCount'] = {}
for i in text.Reviews:
    #   If review is positive
    if i in p:
        #   If comment_id key hasn't been added yet...
        if comment_id in text['commentsCount']:
            text['commentsCount'][comment_id] = 0
        text['commentsCount'][comment_id] += 1
    elif i in n:
        #   if comment_id key hasn't been added yet...
        if comment_id in text['commentsCount']:
            text['commentsCount'][comment_id] = 0
        text['commentsCount'][comment_id] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
In [28]: text  = pd.DataFrame( ['good and not bad', 'it is a terrible bad product', 'excellent product'], columns = ['reviews'])

In [29]: text  
Out[29]: 
                        reviews
0              good and not bad
1  it is a terrible bad product
2             excellent product

In [30]: n = set('bad worse terrible worse bad baddest'.split())
In [31]: p = set('good better excellent good best bestest good'.split())

In [32]: text['count'] = text['reviews'].apply(lambda review: sum(0 + ((word in p) and 1) + ((word in n) and -1) for word in review.split()))

In [33]: text
Out[33]: 
                        reviews  count
0              good and not bad      0
1  it is a terrible bad product     -2
2             excellent product      1
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize

positive_words = set(['good', 'awesome', 'excellent'])
negative_words = set(['bad', 'terrible'])

df = pd.DataFrame( ['good and not bad', 'it is a terrible bad product', 'excellent product'], columns = ['Reviews'])

df['Tokenized'] = df['Reviews'].apply(str.lower).apply(word_tokenize)
df['WordCount'] = df['Tokenized'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))

df['Positive'] = df['WordCount'].apply(lambda x: sum(v for k,v in x.items() if k in positive_words))
df['Negative'] = df['WordCount'].apply(lambda x: sum(v for k,v in x.items() if k in negative_words))
```

Then:

```
>>> df['Sentiment'] = df['Positive'] - df['Negative']
>>> df[['Reviews', 'Sentiment']]
                        Reviews  Sentiment
0              good and not bad          0
1  it is a terrible bad product         -2
2             excellent product          1
```

Above answer loops twice, here's another alternative:

```
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize

positive_words = set(['good', 'awesome', 'excellent'])
negative_words = set(['bad', 'terrible'])

df = pd.DataFrame( ['good and not bad', 'it is a terrible bad product', 'excellent product'], columns = ['Reviews'])

df['Tokenized'] = df['Reviews'].apply(str.lower).apply(word_tokenize)
df['WordCount'] = df['Tokenized'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))

df['Sentiment'] = df['WordCount'].apply(lambda x: sum(v if k in positive_words else -v if k in negative_words else 0 for k,v in x.items()))
```